# Get-only property stays in memory

Tags: ios, swift, memory

I have an enum with get-only property `image`. It seems like every time I read it, it keeps this image in memory and deletes it only after memory warning (since I use multiple enum instances and display their images in a sequence) even after I set another image to the `UIImageView` it was displayed on.

How do I force them to be removed from memory?

Comment: What does your code look like for creating/loading the image?

Comment: @CleverError I just call it by `enumCase.image` and that's it! Although I keep an array of those cases but that shouldn't affect functionality of get-only properties, as far as I know

Comment: @CleverError basically, the line of code looks like this: `imageView.image = enumCase.image` and it's called several times for different enum cases

Comment: But what does the code *inside* your `enum` look like?

Comment: `var image: UIImage{ get{ return UIImage(named: self.rawValue + ".png") } }`

Comment: UIImage will cache images however, and this is generally a good thing. Unless you are using thousands of different images it shouldn't be a problem for you

Comment: @Paulw11 but that's irrational, since I don't even have any references to it. It should be `weak`, should not it?

Comment: @Paulw11 And yes, I see how it is useful since recalling cached images is quicker but my question is how to control it so it does not overload the RAM. For example, if I want to remove the oldest ones from cache and not all at once after memory warning.

Comment: The UIImage class does this internally regardless of the reference you keep. As long as it clears its cache when there is memory pressure (which it does) it shouldn't cause a problem and as I say, unless you are using thousands of different images, UIImage caching on its own shouldn't cause memory pressure. I am guessing you are associating something like an icon image with each state of your enum, and assuming you have no more than a dozen states and an icon is probably less than 20k you aren't talking about much memory

Comment: Have you actually observed that memory use is an issue when your app is running? I mean it is having some sort of negative impact on your app? Have you used the instruments tool to confirm that it is UIImage that is taking memory and not something else?

Comment: If you don't want caching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911663/swift-memory-issues-when-using-uiview-animation-on-a-timer?rq=1

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you, this link is actually useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the best way to not overload the memory is not to cache UIImages in the first place, which can be done with:

```
extension UIImage{

    static func getUcachedImage(named name: String) -> UIImage?{
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(name, ofType: nil)!
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)

        return image
    }

}
```

This is how I solved my problem.